# Combine two ulong values and convert it to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have a problem that I can't solve whole day. I'm new in C# and I'm asking you  tog ive me a hand.

I have two ulong values. I need combine their binary representations and get 16 bytes value. I know C# does not support 128 bit types. But I also do not need to hold this value in variable. I need to convert this value to byte array.
  I tried to combine values like this:

```
long a = ((long)b << 64) + (long)c;
```

and after convert to byte array with BitConverter.

But I realize that this is incorrect, because size of long values is 8 byte.
I don't want to create a 128 type to get result.

So is there a way to combine and add to byte array directly?

Thanks

Comment: `BitConverter` can read from a byte array at an offset, but unfortunately doesn't have any functions to write to an offset within a byte array :(

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft C# supports integers of arbitrary length, using [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). You could combine your two values, such as in the example you have given, like so:

```
BigInteger a = b;
a <<= 64;
a += c;
```

However, as you've indiciated you don't need to store this value. Before you mention, yes, I am aware of endianness. There's machine-dependent endianness and over-the-wire endianness. We should not try to produce any machine-dependent endianness... The way we can produce over-the-wire endianness in the languages I'm most familiar with is using the right-shift and modulo operators, at least for unsigned types. Signed types introduce the complication of encoding the sign, but here's an example I think you might benefit from:

```
byte[] array = { (byte)(b >> 56), (byte)(b >> 48), (byte)(b >> 40), (byte)(b >> 32),
                 (byte)(b >> 24), (byte)(b >> 16), (byte)(b >>  8), (byte)(b      ),
                 (byte)(c >> 56), (byte)(c >> 48), (byte)(c >> 40), (byte)(c >> 32),
                 (byte)(c >> 24), (byte)(c >> 16), (byte)(c >>  8), (byte)(c      ) };
```

Comment: Seems It's what I need... Thanks. But do you know how to get the same result in pl sql? I need to compare the results.

Comment: Very well. I intended to convey a lack of complete confidence with my code. Thanks for your suggestions, @BenVoigt. Do you have any more advice?

Comment: Awesome. @stilhead That's another question, one which I don't have the answer for...

Answer (score 0):

If I run this:

```
var x = (ulong)1;
var y = (ulong)2;

var result =
    BitConverter.GetBytes(x)
        .Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(y))
        .ToArray();
```

I get this:

[image: result]

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its homework?
You can represent your terms, the ulongs a and b as byte arrays.
Afterwards you may create a new byte array c for the sum.
For Each byte go bit by bit and just do a normal two's complement binary addition, remember the carry bit from byte to byte.
If the last byte has carry bit then you should throw "ulong addition overflow exception" of some kind.